# How to make an ssh connection which resumes automatically

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04

I have to SSH to a computer on my network and stay connected. However, my network shuts down from midnight to 7:00 am everyday. What i want is that I be able to auto-reconnect to the computer once the network comes back at 7:00 am. Cron solutions are no good. I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).  It will spew thousands of retry errors from Midnight to 7:00am, but it will reconnect you eventually.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I haven't tested it yet, i guess it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a mechanism that would let an SSH session dally for 7 hours, but [GNU Screen Session Management](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Session-Management) could probably help with disconnecting and reattaching to a shell.

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't help. I think I couldn't exactly figure this out.